# Android application stops on button click

Tags: android, button, if-statement, logging

I am making this application and it just stops when i press some buttons

```
public class Menu3 extends TheMenu{

    Button Buttons[] = new Button[21];
    Intent open = new Intent("com.frosti.lidraedi.OPEN");
    int clicked;
    boolean found;
    int PO1;
    int GoOn;
    int s,e;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    PO1 = b.getInt("PO", 0);

    switch (PO1) {
    case 21:
                    //when i press these buttons everything works well
        setContentView(R.layout.menu21);
        s=0;
        e=11;
        break;
    case 22:
                    //the layout loads without error
                    //but when i press the buttons int the layout it just stops
        setContentView(R.layout.menu22);
        s=12;
        e=15;
        break;
    case 23:
        setContentView(R.layout.menu23);
        s=16;
        e=20;
        break;
    case 24:
        setContentView(R.layout.menu24);
        break;
    case 25:
        setContentView(R.layout.menu25);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    init();
}

private void init() {
    for(int c=s; c <= e; c++){
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf");
        int d = c+1;
        int viewId = getResources().getIdentifier("b"+Integer.toString(d), "id", getPackageName());
        if(viewId!=0){
            Buttons[c] =((Button)findViewById(viewId));
            Buttons[c].setTypeface(tf);
            Log.d("Buttons", Integer.toString(c)+" : "+Integer.toString(d));
        }else{
            Log.d("Buttons", "0");
        }
    }
}

public void ButtonOnClick(View v){
    Log.d("ButtonOnClick", "I was clicked");
    found=false;
    int c= 0;
    for(Button b:Buttons){
        Log.d("for loop", "I got run");
        if(b.getId() == v.getId()){
            Log.d("if block", "I got found");
            GoOn=c;
            Log.d("M3:true:C", Integer.toString(c)+ " : "+Integer.toString(v.getId()));
            found=true;
            break;
        }
        Log.d("C var", "I will get incremented");
        c++;  //hehehe
        Log.d("C var", "I got incremented");
    }
    Log.i("ButtonOnClick",Integer.toString(c));
    if(found) {
        Log.i("M3:clicked:GoOn",Integer.toString(GoOn));
        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();

        b1.putInt("GoOn",GoOn);

        open.putExtras(b1);
        Log.d("Activity", "I will get opened");
        startActivity(open);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }else if(clicked != v.getId()){
        clicked = v.getId();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Skjárinn fannst því miður ekki",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

ok so i open the application press menu 22(that executes case 22 in the switch block) press some button and it stops
These are the errors i get:
[image: The errors i get.]

If you compare the image with the code you see it executes "Log.d("for loop", "I got run");" but then freaks out, so error should be in this line " if(b.getId() == v.getId()){" but i have no idea why this happens?

This is the xml layout code just in case if it helps.

[image: The button layout code]

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this

Comment: what is line 84 @ `menu3`?

Comment: it is `if(b.getId() == v.getId()){`

Comment: where you initialize `Buttons` in your code?

Comment: `public class Menu3 extends TheMenu{`  
    `Button Buttons[] = new Button[21];`

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following loop right after you initialize Buttons, just to be sure of what you have:

```
for(Button b : Buttons){
    Log.d("Have button with ID " + b.getId());
```

Then run the same loop at the start of your onClick(). That will at least tell you if your Buttons structure is sound. When in doubt of which item is causing a NPE, it helps to log them separately. Often times, it's a non-obvious lifetime error, especially with fragments.

Answer (score 2):

you create one array of Button with:

```
Button Buttons[] = new Button[21];
```

but you have custom item in that between `s` to `e` (you get value from switch statement ).

as you don't have button in all index of your array you get `NPE` on `b.getId()`, because you don't have any button on some index.

so you can solve your problem with two way.

1- as you don't know size of your array you can use `ArrayList`

2- you need initialize your array in `init` with

```
Buttons[] = new Button[e - s];  // or e-s+1 test both
```

I suggest use `ArrayList`, so your code must be like:

```
 ArrayList<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Then you can get all id in your code with:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++)
      list.get(i).getId();
```